# Can I use a value as a key for another dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

What I'm trying to do is have a dict that goes like

```
((category1: subcategory1, sub2, sub3), (cat2: sub12, sub22...))
```

However, I also want the subcategories to have their own values as well:

```
((subcat1: subitem1, subitem2), (subcat2: subitem12, subitem22)...)
```

I want to be able to reference the subitem such that it connects to the original category, not just subcategory.  Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:

```
import json
import win32com.client as win32
from glob import glob
import io
import locale
from collections import defaultdict
import pprint
#import re
#importing needed clients

raw_files = glob('*.xlsx')
x = locale.getpreferredencoding()
print x
ex = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
ex.Visible = False
oFile = open("rawsort.txt", "w+")
#oFile = io.open("rawsort.txt", "w+", encoding = "utf-8")#text dump

for f in raw_files:
ex.Workbooks.Open(f)
sheet = ex.ActiveWorkbook


#print sheet.Sheets("MRD").Cells(1,2).Value
wincs = sheet.Worksheets('MRD')
if sheet.Sheets("MRD").Cells(1, 3).Value== None:
    wincs.Cells(1,3).Value = u'N/A'
if sheet.Sheets("MRD").Cells(1, 4).Value== None:
    wincs.Cells(1,4).Value = u'N/A'
if sheet.Sheets("MRD").Cells(1, 5).Value== None:
    wincs.Cells(1,5).Value = u'N/A'
if not wincs.Cells(1,2).Value == None:
            category[sheet.Sheets('MRD').Cells(1,2).Value][wincs.Cells(1,3).Value][wincs.Cells(1,4).Value] = wincs.Cells(1,5).Value
   # print listy
print sheet.Sheets('MRD').UsedRange.Rows.Count
for x in xrange(2, sheet.Sheets("MRD").UsedRange.Rows.Count+1):#for loop to print     through paragraphs
        if sheet.Sheets("MRD").Cells(x, 3).Value== None:
            wincs.Cells(x,3).Value = u'N/A'
        if sheet.Sheets("MRD").Cells(x, 4).Value== None:
            wincs.Cells(x,4).Value = u'N/A'
        if sheet.Sheets("MRD").Cells(x, 5).Value== None:
                wincs.Cells(x,5).Value = u'N/A'
        if not sheet.Sheets("MRD").Cells(x, 2).Value== None:       
                category[sheet.Sheets('MRD').Cells(x,2).Value][wincs.Cells(x,3).Value][wincs.Cells(x,4).Value] = wincs.Cells(x,5).Value
#oFile.write(unicode(listy))
oFile.write("\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n")

oFile.close()
```

However, this is my output:

[image: problems]

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a tree data structure. Have a look at [this github gist](https://gist.github.com/hrldcpr/2012250) for an example of how you implement one with dictionaries in python.

Comment: Hey, I took a look at the website and ran it in my code.  I'm running into a couple errors, will edit my post

Answer (score 1):

You could store it like this:

```
categories = {
    'category1': {
         'subcat1': ['subitem1', 'subitem2'],
         'subcat2': ['subitem12', 'subitem22']
    },
    'category2': {
        # ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is, indeed, possible to use a value as a key in another dict. We do that all the time in the testing framework that we have where I work. In our case, we have one dictionary that contains all of the entries with the expected keys, while the other dictionaries each have a value in it called ID, whose value is a key in the first dictionary. The way you do it is as follows:

```
value = dict1[dict2["key"]]
```

where "key" is, of course, the name of the value in dict2 that contains the key in dict1.

Of course, you may want to play it safe by assigning `dict2["key"]` to an intermediate variable (let's call it `key` for our example) and then check if that actually is a key in the first dictionary, like so:

```
key = dict2["key"]
if dict1.has_key(key):
    value = dict1[key]
else:
    value = None
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, but dictionaries can only have one key and one value associated together, unless you want the value to be a tuple or list

you can think of a dictionary as a lookup

```
>>>ages = {'Jenny':26, 'Mike':30}
>>>ages['Mike']
30
```

here is an example

```
Dict2[Dict1['category1']]
```

Comment: Wait, not it's not. `ages['Jenny':26, 'Mike':30]` actually calls `ages.__getitem__((slice('Jenny', 26), slice('Mike', 30)))`... Still, it's wrong.

Comment: fixed it just ran in my console, sorry for the mistake